# Abort Routing and continue with the original request in .NET

Tags: c#, routes

I want to use routing for all incomming calls to my server and then only use the routing on some of these (depending on values in my database).

I know how routing is done, what I don't know is how to abort routing inside my IRouteHandler.

ex

```
if (routing) 
{
  // do routing 
    var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, typeof(IHttpHandler)) as IHttpHandler;
    return page;
}
else 
{
  // proceed as if no routing has been made
}
```

Comment: You need to add more information.

Comment: I actually dont know what more info is needed. I need a way to abort the routing inside the routing. Is there a way to get the initial request and then return it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Respone.Redirect()
```

Then you redirect them to a error or default page.

Comment: thanks, but that would not work since all pages is routed. Actually I don't know how to route all incomming calls yet, but that can't be to hard :)